# найти максимальную сумму среди А1+А16 , А2+А15 ... А8+А9

Tags: pascal

```
var arr : array [1..16] of integer;
  i,maxsum : integer;
  begin
    for i:=1 to 16 do
      begin 
        write('arr[',i,']=');
        readln(arr[i]);
      end;
    maxsum:=arr[1]+arr[16];
    for i:=1 to 16 do 
      if arr[i]+arr[i]>maxsum then
        maxsum:=arr[i]+arr[i];
    writeln('Массив arr: ');
    for i:=1 to 16 do 
      writeln(arr[i]:5);
    writeln('maxsum= ', maxsum);
  end.
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибки в индексировании массива. Так будет правильнее:

```
var 
  arr : array [1..16] of integer;
  i,maxsum : integer;

  begin
    for i:=1 to 16 do
      begin 
        write('arr[',i,']=');
        readln(arr[i]);
      end;  // пусть так, хотя можно и проще сделать ввод
    maxsum:=arr[1]+arr[16];

    for i:=2 to 8 do  // первый член выбрасываем, вторую половину массива тоже
      if (arr[i]+arr[17-i])>maxsum then
        maxsum:=arr[i]+arr[17-i];
    writeln('Массив arr: ');
    for i:=1 to 8 do 
      writeln(arr[2*i-1]:5, ' ', arr[2*i]:5); // так все же красивее. Можно даже 4x4
    writeln('maxsum= ', maxsum);
  end.
```